# What is the C# equivalent of NSMutableArray and NSArray?

Tags: c#, objective-c, .net, cocoa

What is the C# equivalent of `NSMutableArray` and `NSArray`?

Does C# have a mutable and non-mutable? I noticed that `string` appears to be mutable by default.

As a bonus, how do I quickly populate the array in C#?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That would be `ArrayList` and `object[]` respectively, if you take the weak typing nature of `NSMutableArray` and `NSArray` into account.

Arrays and lists in C# (at least for .NET 2.0 and above) can also be strongly-typed, so depending on what kind of object you're storing you can specify that type. For example if you only have `NSString` objects in an `NSMutableArray` in your Objective-C code, you'd use `List<string>`, and if you have them in an `NSArray`, you'd use `string[]` with a fixed size instead.

To quickly initialize and populate a list or an array in C#, you can use what's known as a [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
string[] array = { "foo", "bar", "baz" }; // Shortcut syntax for arrays
```

---

`string` in C# is immutable, just like `NSString` in the Foundation framework. Every time you assign a new string to a variable, you simply point or refer the variable to a different object.

Comment: Didn't realize that about strings. Thanks

Comment: Quick question... how do I make a weak List? Your example shows a strongly typed List.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use weakly-typed collections anymore, but if you need to you can use a non-generic `ArrayList`.

Comment: A `NSArray` is completely immutable: you can't replace existing members of the array, so it's not exactly the same as `object[]`. `NSArray` itself, as far as I know, has no exact equivalent in the .NET Framework (but it's not much of a problem either).

Comment: @zneak: Ahhh yes... I knew I'd missed something. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Someone should make a ImmutableList<>, whose elements can only be set at creation. Or we get on with our lives...

Answer (score 6):

```
List<String> stringList = new List<String>();
stringList.Add("Test");
```

String in C# is immutable.
The equivalent of NSMutableString in C# is StringBuilder.
C#, unlike Objective-C doesn't represent the method intention clearly on the method name.
For example, both classes String and StringBuilder has a method called Replace that you might think, replaces characters.
String.Replace replaces and returns the new string whereas
StringBuilder.Replace does a in-place replace.

Most methods in most classes in C# (and Java too) work like that.

In Obj-C, naming conventions are clear, it's either

```
[NSString stringByReplacing...]
[NSMutableString replace...]
```

Answer (score -2):

For Xamarin.iOS in C#:

```
string[] pickerItemsArray;

pickerItemsArray = new string[]{"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"};
```

Comment: Using `string[]` instead of a `List` or `ArrayList` means this object in memory is still immutable.